# How to generate random numbers

Tags: vb6

i'm new to vb and i have 3 textboxs that i want to set it to a random value when the user click a specific button in in the form so :
here's the code :

```
Private Sub cmdjouer_Click(Index As Integer)
  txt1 = Math.Randomize(9)
 txt2 = Math.Randomize(9)
 txt3 = Math.Randomize(9)
End Sub
```

i get the following error
       `expected function or variable`

i'm sure that the problom is with the Randomize function.

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: Use `Rnd` instead. So instead of `Math.Randomixe(9)`, you use `Int((Rnd*9)+1)` to get a random integer between 1 and 9.

Comment: Apart from what has already been mentioned here if txt1 is a TextBox you probably want txt1.Text =

Comment: @David Those are old VB6 functions that are only provided in VB.NET for backwards compatibility. The Random class is preferable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are confusing VB.NET with VB6.  They are drastically different from each other.  In the future, when you look for examples, documentation, and help online, be sure to specify VB6 to ensure that you are dealing with the correct language.  They are essentially two completely different languages.

### VB6

In VB6, you need to initially seed the random number generator using the `Randomize` function.  Then, to generate a random number, you must use the `Rnd` function, for instance:

```
Private Sub cmdjouer_Click(Index As Integer)
    Randomize()
    txt1.Text = Int((Rnd * 9) + 1)
    txt2.Text = Int((Rnd * 9) + 1)
    txt3.Text = Int((Rnd * 9) + 1)
End Sub
```

### VB.NET

`Math.Randomize` is a method in the Smart Personal Objects Technology (SPOT) namespace.  I doubt that is what you are actually looking for.  You probably just want to use the `System.Random` class, like this:

```
Private Sub cmdjouer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdjouer.Click
    Dim r As New Random()
    txt1.Text = r.Next(9).ToString()
    txt2.Text = r.Next(9).ToString()
    txt3.Text = r.Next(9).ToString()
End Sub
```

As others have pointed out, you don't want to set your text box reference variable to the number (e.g. `txt1 = ...`).  You need to set the `Text` property of the text box.

Also, as was pointed out in the comments below, I called `Randomize` or created the `New Random` object inside the button's `Click` event.  I did so to simplify the example, but in actuality, that would be bad practice.  In either case, the seeding of the random number generator should, ideally, only happen once, typically when the application starts.  By re-seeding the generator each time, it can cause the results to be less random.

Comment: i get this error : Syntax error it's a problem with   Dim r As New Random() . So how to import System.Random class in VB .Sorry for silly question . i wrote it like that : Dim r As New System.Random() but it didn't work . Many thanks

Comment: What kind of project is it?  What version of visual studio are you using?  Which version of the .NET framework is the project targeting?

Comment: VB6 ,Win32 Console application

Comment: You tagged this question as VB.NET, which is drastically different from VB6.  That is why the answers to your question don't work.  The functions you need to use in VB6 are `Randomize` and `Rnd`.  I will update my answer for VB6.

Comment: Note that you should only call (VB^'s) `Randomize` once on application startup.

Answer (score 2):

You should [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee435671.aspx).

`Microsoft.SPOT.Math.Randomize` says:

> Sets a random starting point for random number generation.

So it doesn’t generate random numbers, it *initialises* the generator. You want [`Microsoft.SPOT.Math.Random`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee435673.aspx). But better yet, use the superior [`Random` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) to generate random numbers.

The code has more problems, however. As Constanta mentioned in a comment, `txt1` etc. are probably text boxes so you need to change your assignments to say `txt1.Text = …` etc. However, that is *still* bad code and won’t compile with `Option Strict On`. [Which should **always be `On`**.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14840761/1968) So you need to convert manually, leaving you with this code:

```
Dim rng As New Random()
txt1.Text = rng.Next(9).ToString()
txt2.Text = rng.Next(9).ToString()
txt3.Text = rng.Next(9).ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
' Initialize the random-number generator.
Randomize()
' Generate random value between 1 and 6.
Dim value As Integer = CInt(Int((6 * Rnd()) + 1)) txt1.text = cstr(value)
```

Comment: Those are old VB6 functions that are only provided in VB.NET for backwards compatibility.  The `Random` class is preferable.

Comment: I am an old vb6 man. But i am happy it stil works. I have to use the new VB.Net way i know :)