# How to create a Randomly Generated number

Tags: vb6

I currently Have this code in VB6.

```
Option Explicit

Dim RandomNum As Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()

   randomize

   Label1.Caption = RandomNum = Int((Rnd * 10) + 1)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not assigning the random value to your variable or the label correctly.

Change:

```
Label1.Caption = RandomNum = Int((Rnd * 10) + 1)
```

To:

```
RandomNum = Int((Rnd * 10) + 1)
If Random >= 1 And RandomNum <=3 Then
    Label1.Caption = "Option1"
Else
    Label1.Caption = "Option2"
End If
```

You can also look into using a `Select Case` statement.

Comment: Could i also just use lable1.caption = Int((Rnd * 10) + 1)

Comment: Sure you could.  It just seemed like you needed to store that value  in your class level variable since you went thru the trouble of declaring it: `Dim RandomNum As Integer`

Comment: How would i use this number to choose an option for me. for example, if the random number generated is between 1 to 3 make the caption of a label = "Option1" and if its 4 to 6 make it "Option2".

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963493/how-to-generate-random-numbers) is the answer by #steven-doggart.

"In VB6, you need to initially seed the random number generator using the `Randomize` function. Then, to generate a random number, you must use the `Rnd` function, for instance.."

Comment: but i have int((rnd * 10) + 1)

Comment: What is it exactly printing, can you share? The code  'int((rnd * 10) + 1)' is suppose to print Random integer from 1-10.

Comment: False or sometimes true.

Answer (score 0):

I have this function for randomizing with limits :) Hope this may help you also.

```
Public Function Random(Upper As Integer, Lower As Integer) As Integer
Randomize
Random = Int(Upper * Rnd() + Lower)
End Function
```