# VB.Net true and false Operators

Tags: vb.net

Does VB.Net have `true` and `false` operators like C# does?

Until this morning, I was not aware that C# has `true` and `false` "operator"s.
I found them listed in a book, along with the normal operators (`&`, `^`, `|`, `&&`, etc.).
At first I thought it was a misprint; I thought that `true` and `false` were only `Boolean` values, not operators.
I found this MSDN page: [true Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d(v=vs.110).aspx) about C#'s `true` operator, but was unable to find anything about VB's `True` operator (if it even exists).

Comment: Please expand what you mean by True and False operators

Comment: [`True`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0y616xy(v=vs.90).aspx) and [`False`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75k39e8h(v=vs.90).aspx) are the two possible values of the [`Boolean` DataType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wts33hb3(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why C# fails to compare two object types with each other but VB doesn't?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837209/why-c-sharp-fails-to-compare-two-object-types-with-each-other-but-vb-doesnt)

Comment: @kenorb: very far-fetched

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Sorry for the lack of explanation in my question before.  I've edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has the [`IsTrue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93xa16x4.aspx) and [`IsFalse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6tz4ad8.aspx) overload operators.

Comment: Thank you!    [IsTrue Operator (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93xa16x4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, they are `True` and `False`.

**But** note that `True` in VB.NET evaluates to -1.

VB.NET also has the logical operators `Not`, `And`, `Xor`, &c.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Are they used the same as in C#?  [true Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You probably caught this, but I'm meaning operators, not just Boolean values.  (I should have explained my question better originally).  So, if there really are VB True and False operators, then I will mark your answer (as answer).  Thanks again.

Comment: The logical operators I cite are broadly equivalent to the c# operators.

Comment: Thank you!  Due to lack of reputation points, S.O. does not yet allow me to mark answer.